# Arial Regular not render in Flash properly - incorrect lineheight

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts

I am embeding many fonts in a Flash Application.

Similar to the Mac font rendering problem in Flash, the line height has all of a sudden started rendering really large for Arial Regular. The font size is the correct but the line height is wrong. This is not true for Bold, but is for Italics as well.

Anyone experience this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is discussed here:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/5421454

There is no clear fix for all situations in which leading is wrong outside not using Adobe Flash CC. My initial suspicion that adding all Glyphs to the embeded Font solved the leading problem does not appear to be a good general fix. There is no good solution. For example one solution is to set the leading to something like -50 for a Font of 20 pt in size.

I am unsure if Adobe has the motivation to fix this one based on the Forum thread. Really disappointing.